# Curvature of plane curves on a surface

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Let $S$ be a surface and $\gamma$ a curve on $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ obtained cutting $S$ with a plane. I wuold  an upper bound for the curvature of $\gamma$. Are there papers for this topic?

Comment: Does the plane contain the normal direction?

Comment: My surface is in the euclidean space.

Comment: Upper bounds in terms of what?

Comment: You are more likely to have a lower bound. It seems to me that the curvature can grow a lot when the plane gets closer to the tangent.

Comment: For Igor...in terms of the gaussian curvature and slope of the plane respect to the gauss map.

Answer (score 2):

Getting bounds from *Gaussian* curvature is hopeless due to examples like the pseudosphere, but assuming that the *principal* curvatures are at most $1$ one should be able to show that the curvature of the intersection should be bounded above by $\sec \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is the angle with the normal vector.